# c++ - llvm and runtime jit

Tags: c++, gcc, llvm, jit, self-modifying

### Context

Linux 64 bits / osx 64 bits. C++ (gcc 5.1, llvm 3.6.1)

Up to now, I always used gcc for my projects.
The problem for the next thing I am creating is the licence. Hence, I decided to give clang/llvm a go.

My needs : runtime self modifying code (and a very relaxed licence for compiler plugins for static analysis and other things.).

I played a lot with [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/JIT) and it works fine.

As for llvm, I read the Kaleidoscope project and some doc but it is unclear.

#### Question

I saw that llvm has some jit possibilities but I am not sure if it enables to self modify the code (more precisely, extend the code) at runtime as libgccjit does for c++ language.

I just need a starter here, llvm is huge and new to me, so anyone expert enough is very welcome to guide me a bit.